# How can I extend the Hub control to support an ItemsSource property like the Panorama control

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

My understanding is that the new Hub control is supposed to replace the Panorama control in Windows Phone 8.1.  However, the new Hub control does not have an ItemsSource property like the Panorama control did.  I can still use the Pivot control, which supports the ItemsSource property, but its only available in my phone project.  I would like to use the Hub control because it is available in both the Phone and Store projects.

Is it possible to extend the Hub control somehow so that it supports any given number of HubSections, depending on how many section items are provided to it via the ItemsSource collection?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want to do is something like `Hub.ItemsSource` to create the different `HubSection` for you? This is *dramatically* against the recommendations of the control team. There are several reasons. The first is the intent of the control to be a curated list of items meant for the Hub page of your app. The second has to do with performance.

Having said that, there is nothing to stop you from creating an `Attached Property` that implements the same concept you are wanting. But dynamic `HubSection` are simply not how the control is intended. You might want to comment back saying "Then how is it supposed to replace the `Panorama` control?" The reality is, the `Hub` control is the closest thing we have to a `Panorama` control, not a one-for-one replacement.

I bet, for sure, you can live without it. But you certainly are not the first to ask. Developers want everything to be as dynamic as possible. But that isn't actually best for performance. And, performance is worth a second consideration here. I think, like you, a lot of developers are going to be rewiring as they start to build universal apps instead of Silverlight apps. I'm sorry it's not one for one.

Comment: The Pivot control supports ItemSource, so I'm wondering if the performance concern for a Hub is similar to the performance concern for a Pivot. Also, according to [the article at this link](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2014/01/05/Using-the-Windows-81-Hub-as-an-ItemsControl.aspx), would it be simpler to subclass the Hub control or are there advantages to using attached properties as mentioned in your answer instead?

Comment: I am going to go back to the fact that you cannot virtualize a `HubSection` (explaining performance). But at the same time, yes, I think sub classing would get you the same result and maybe even give you a cleaner implementation. I don't want to come off as recommending what you are wanting to do here. But it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution from Diederik Krols - http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2014/01/05/Using-the-Windows-81-Hub-as-an-ItemsControl.aspx

Comment: This is the best solution I could find also and included it in my comment to the answer provided by @JerryNixon.  Have you tried this solution and can you verify that it works well in a published application?